# @Inject is not injecting the full HttpClient module

Tags: angular

I have a Module that is a library. Within it is a simple service that calls an api:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(@Inject(MY_INJECTION_TOKEN) private http: HttpClient) {}
  test() {
    return this.http.get('some_api')
  }
}


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class ServicesModule {
 static forChild(
  config: { http: Provider },
 ): ModuleWithProviders<ServicesModule> {
   return { 
    ngModule: ServicesModule,
    providers: { provide: MY_INJECTION_TOKEN, useValue: config.http }
  }
}
```

That is used in another library. We'll call that `ParentModule`

```js
@NgModule({
 imports: [ServicesModule],
})
export class ParentModule {
  static forRoot(
   config: { http: Provider, someOtherConfigs?: T }
  ): ModuleWithProviders<ParentModule> {
   return {
    ngModule: ParentModule,
    providers: [
     { provide: MY_INJECTION_TOKEN, useValue: config.http },
     { provide: DIFFERENT_INJECTION_TOKEN, useValue: config.someOtherConfigs },
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

Finally those exportable libs find themselves on the main app. We'll call this `AppModule`:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
   HttpClientModule,
   ParentModule.forRoot({ http: HttpClientModule }),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Alright everything looks good. No runtime errors. If I didn't include `HttpClientModule` there would be. So everything looks to work as expected.

However as soon as the user interacts with anything in `ParentModule` that uses `ServicesModule` I see an error:

```
TypeError: this.http.get is not a function
```

If I console log the `this.http`, I see `class HttpClientModule {}` WTF?

And this problem persist even if I don't use `ParentModule` and use the `ServicesModule` by itself. Like:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
   HttpClientModule,
   ServicesModule.forChild({ http: HttpClientModule }),
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What am I doing wrong? This should work.

Comment: I feel there is some kind of a patch from different source snippets in your code. Are you the author for all the code or you copied from different sources?

Comment: Nope, I'm the author. I am vastly simplifying my code so there could be errors in there.